# What is "_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_"?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I implemented my own `__getattr__()` to loosely handle any non-existent attributes.

I just so happened to define this class in a Jupyter notebook to experiment with it interactively.

IPython creates `_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_` due to this `__getattr__` implementation – and **I'd like to understand what this is and how to "clean it up" is possible.**

There is [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2014) opened about it, but it's not clear to my why – if it checks for permissive handling within `__getattr__` – it doesn't check to see that **_repr_html_** *is* implemented in the OP's example?

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Metabox(SimpleNamespace):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """
        Create a new namespace for any non-existing attributes.
        """
        print("calling __getattr__")
        self.__dict__[name] = Metabox()
        return self.__dict__[name]
```

Comment: It maybe caused by ipython trying to test if an instance `a` of your class `hasattr(a, '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_')`, and `hasattr` [by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) called `__getattr__`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As taper mentioned in above comments; IPython sometimes needs to inspect  objects to know whether they have some methods.

To handle object like yours; that always say "yes", when we have doubt we probe for this name; and if the object says "yep, I got that !" we know the object lies and implemented a `__getattr__`.