# Python for Smartsheet - Getting _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-api-1.1

All - I am getting this error when loading the Smartsheet Client
I loaded all dependencies as per requirements. 
What should I fix?

ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_
ImportError! Could not load api or model class _ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_

Also this is what I am trying to run (TOKEN # Garbled)

```
import smartsheet
import logging
import os.path


access_token = 'TOKENNUMBER'
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(access_token)
smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine, the error is linked to `ipython`.

If you run this code directly in python shell you should not have any error. You should probably avoid `ipython` if possible. For more information about this error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56317537/2320342